# Exchange 2010 is sending emails from accounts that do not exist?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, spam-prevention, exchange-server-2010, email-spam

All of a sudden, our exchange server has started sending out emails to `.com.br` addresses from accounts that do not exist in our organization. For example:

```
sadfjkh32@myorganization.com

sasdfsdkh4352@myorganization.com

sadhdf@myorganization.com
```

Please help.

Comment: Looks like someone in your organization has got a virus. The error is I'm almost sure not in the Exchange server, and I think you'd be better off asking this on serverfault or superuser...

Answer (score 0):

You should review your recieve connector configuration to make sure you are not allowing someone to relay mail over your server.
Aditionally use the message tracking in esm and look for those emails.
Try to find the source IP address of those emails, meaning where they are generated.
Are they generating from an application server on your network. Maybe a scanner device, a pc...

As soon as you find the ip address you will have a better idea what is going on

Liran Zamir